# MySQL indexing and data access time complexity

Tags: mysql, indexing, time, complexity-theory

in `MySQL` i read that data access time complexity when we have an indexing over a specific data column is `log(n)` because of using a BTree, do there any scenario that data access time became more that `log(n)` for example `O(n)`, because when we insert data in sorted manner into a BTree the tree grows in one side and data access complexity grows to `O(n)` do they have any policy on inserting data into this indexing BTree ?? thanks for answering

Comment: *"[...] data access complexity grows to O(n)"* No matter how much rows you have, complexity can't reach `O(n)` for reading, thanks to the B-Tree structure. [This](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree) is a good reading, IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to note:

- Disk accesses are far more important (to performance) than O().
- A "Rule of Thumb":  A node has 100 sub-nodes (or leaf elements).  Hence...
- In a typical InnoDB BTree (data or index), a million-row table will be only about 3 levels deep.  For a *trillion* rows, about 6 levels.  That is the primary place where "log n" comes into play.
- BTrees, if augmented bottom-up, stayed balanced.
- In MySQL, don't worry about the BTrees; there are worse things to deal with -- indexing, formulation of queries, etc.
- InnoDB uses `B+Trees`, making index-scans reasonably efficient by not having to drill-down the tree each time it exhausts the elements of a node.
- Wikipedia is another useful reference.